# Store Kofax 10.2 Batch configuration in version control

Tags: version-control, kofax

When you export Batch configuration in **Kofax 10.2** through UI it generates a cab file.

There a bunch of binary files like `dlls` in that cab file. That kind of kills an ability to store it in version-control system.

Having those configuration file in version control would allow better/easier code sharing/testing/deployment/automation.

So I have 3 questions:

1. Is there way to export version-control friendly batch configuration?
2. Is there way to integrate Kofax with version control directly?
3. Are there any plans to add this functionality in future versions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the short answers to all of your questions are No.

Despite the fact that it has no granularity, you should store the whole cab file in source control, since that is what you would use if you needed to restore your configuration to a previous state.

Within the cab file, the primary item that holds the batch configuration is the admin.xml file.  If you really felt the need you could extract the contents of the cab file and also store these in source control.  If you were to diff versions of the admin xml you may be able to determine context about what changed in the batch class.  However you would still only be able to restore the full cab file.

Additionally, you mentioned dlls in the cab file, so I assume that you have Validation Scripts or something similar.  Not only the built dlls, but also the source code would be within the cab in folders like Scripts\00000001[DocumentClassName].  So again, keeping the extracted contents in source control might be a good way to be able to diff changes, etc.  But you still do need to keep the full cab since that is the only way you can import the batch class configuration.

Comment: A knew those answers... But optimist in me still asked. Too bad. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that Stephen said in his answer, and...

For some of the types of configuration management, version control, and troubleshooting tasks in the Kofax environment, I have found Beyond Compare by Scooter Software to be supremely helpful in comparing the contents of two .cab files and reconciling differences between them.

I'm speaking specifically of comparing cab files containing Kofax batch classes, which also contain the document class information for the document types in the batch class, as well as other things like assigned users, etc.

This will work best if your cab files have only one batch class in each, the same one, e.g., before and after cab snapshots, for the same batch class.

In Beyond Compare (BC) (I'm using the 4.x version), from Windows Explorer you select one .cab file for the left side, and the .cab file you are comparing it to for the right side.  BC will show you the files inside each cab file, and as Stephen said, the admin.xml is the one with the details.

You can actually copy XML lines from one side to the other in BC, and save the result, but the real value is in seeing what settings changed between versions of the batch class.

If Kofax had some sort of scriptable automation API for the admin module, that would be amazing and potentially enable many of the capabilities you describe, but if Kofax does have such an API, I am unaware of it.  I'm currently running Kofax Capture 10.1.

In Kofax version 11, they did add some features for keeping versions of batch classes automatically for you, so you can audit changes that were made in the admin module. Didn't notice anything about an automation API for the admin module in Kofax 11.